# Expresiones regulares validar y restringir

Tags: html, jquery, regex, validación, jquery-validate

buenas tardes! Quiero saber como puedo hacer que un input text a través de jQuery pueda aceptar caracteres especiales y símbolos, pero que no puedan usar estos

```
' " \ / < > = * @ &
```

Porque he intentado de varias formas pero he fallado rotundamente.

Si se puede hacer a con patrones mejor porque lo aplicaría directamente a

```
//Caracteres validos
    if (/[A-Za-z0-9_]/.test(value)) return this.show_status(el, 'error', 'S&oacute;lo se permiten letras, n&uacute;meros y guiones(_)');
```

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Un caracter que no sea ninguno de esos símbolos (el `^` niega a la clase de caracteres)

```
[^'"\\\/<>=*@&]
```

Desde el inicio del texto (`^` acá tiene un significado diferente), 0 o más veces (`*`) hasta el final del texto (`$`):

```
^[^'"\\\/<>=*@&]*$
```

```js
const input = document.getElementById('texto'),
      salida = document.getElementById('salida'),
      regex = /^[^'"\\\/<>=*@&]*$/;

input.addEventListener('input', evaluarTexto);

function evaluarTexto(ev) {
    if (regex.test(ev.target.value)) {
        salida.innerText = 'Coincide';
    } else {
        salida.innerText = 'No coincide';
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto">
<p id="salida">
```